# Creating a JSON folder tree using Python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, data-structures

I have a unique problem at hand. There is a list that contains the output of ls from a Unix command. I have to extract the filenames and put them in a JSON tree, where the parents form the folder structure and files/empty folder become the last offspring.

I am able to do it for a single item in the list but I am unable to apply it to the entire list to get a summarized JSON.

Here is my trial:

```py
input_str_list = [
  '2023-06-27 13:10:31        772 dexter/lab_report/inventory/rider/jointball/rotatable/archive/LOGS/hammer_file_download_202105011701.log',
  '2023-06-27 13:10:31        772 dexter/lab_report/inventory/rider/jointball/rotatable/LOGS/hammer_file_download_202112021849.log',
  '2023-06-27 13:10:31        146 dexter/lab_report/inventory/rider/jointball/rotatable/SUMMARY/SUMMARY_rotatable_report_2022-04-01.csv',
  '2023-06-27 13:10:32        145 dexter/lab_report/consumable/fastner/jointball/stopscrew/SUMMARY/SUMMARY_stopscrew/SUMMARY_stopscrew_report_2022-04-11.csv'
  ]

for inp_str in input_str_list:
    tree_dict = {}
    test_list = inp_str.split(' ')
    while "" in test_list:
        test_list.remove("")
    file_struct = test_list[-1].split('/')
    for key in reversed(file_struct):
        if key != file_struct[-1]:
            tree_dict = {key: tree_dict}
        else:
            tree_dict = key

    tree_dict_json = json.dumps(tree_dict)
    print(tree_dict_json)
```

My output (done over 4 individual iterations):
[image]

Required output:
[image]

Can someone in the Python community please help me solve this and help me generate the required pattern?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you can spilt using `re.split` to avoid removing empty strings manually. Then you can use a *recursive function* to create your keys/dictionaries at any levels:

```py
import re
import json

input_str_list = [
  '2023-06-27 13:10:31        772 dexter/lab_report/inventory/rider/jointball/rotatable/archive/LOGS/hammer_file_download_202105011701.log',
  '2023-06-27 13:10:31        772 dexter/lab_report/inventory/rider/jointball/rotatable/LOGS/hammer_file_download_202112021849.log',
  '2023-06-27 13:10:31        146 dexter/lab_report/inventory/rider/jointball/rotatable/SUMMARY/SUMMARY_rotatable_report_2022-04-01.csv',
  '2023-06-27 13:10:32        145 dexter/lab_report/consumable/fastner/jointball/stopscrew/SUMMARY/SUMMARY_stopscrew/SUMMARY_stopscrew_report_2022-04-11.csv'
  ]

tree_dict = {}

def add_keys(d, l):
    if len(l) > 2:
        d.setdefault(l[0], {})
        add_keys(d[l[0]], l[1:])
    else:
        d[l[0]] = l[1]

for inp_str in input_str_list:
    _, _, _, path = re.split(r'\s+', inp_str)
    add_keys(tree_dict, path.split('/'))

print(json.dumps(tree_dict, indent=4))
```

Output:

```json
{
    "dexter": {
        "lab_report": {
            "inventory": {
                "rider": {
                    "jointball": {
                        "rotatable": {
                            "archive": {
                                "LOGS": "hammer_file_download_202105011701.log"
                            },
                            "LOGS": "hammer_file_download_202112021849.log",
                            "SUMMARY": "SUMMARY_rotatable_report_2022-04-01.csv"
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            "consumable": {
                "fastner": {
                    "jointball": {
                        "stopscrew": {
                            "SUMMARY": {
                                "SUMMARY_stopscrew": "SUMMARY_stopscrew_report_2022-04-11.csv"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thankyou
Its working perfectly. But I got stuck in a situation where folders are same but files are different. e.g. 
`input_str_list = [
'2023-08-01 11:28:46 772 dexter/lab_report/inventory/rider/jointball/rotatable/LOGS/hammer_file_download_202207301156.log',
'2023-08-02 10:35:21 772 dexter/lab_report/inventory/rider/jointball/rotatable/LOGS/hammer_file_download_202208011119.log',
'2023-08-03 22:12:17 772 dexter/lab_report/inventory/rider/jointball/rotatable/LOGS/hammer_file_download_202208022132.log']`
how do I show all the files in the folder as a list ?

Comment: Then just create/append to a list whenever you reach the end of your tree: replace `d[l[0]] = l[1]` with `d.setdefault(l[0], []).append(l[1])` in `add_keys`

Comment: superb ! works like a charm. I understood the concept of setdefault now. Thanks a ton!

Comment: The logic works perfectly for all cases except one where the next file is one folder short of the previous one.

`input_str_list = [ '2023-08-01 11:28:46 772 dexter/lab_report/inventory/rider/jointball/rotatable/LOGS/hammer_file_download_202207301156.log',  '2023-08-02 10:35:21 772 dexter/lab_report/inventory/rider/jointball/rotatable/hammer_file_download_202208011119.log']`
Any ideas/suggestions to handle this case ?

Comment: You could introduce a dummy key at the end of the tree associated with the list of files: `d.setdefault('_files', []).append(l[0])` instead of `d[l[0]] = l[1]`. Also change the `if` statement to `if len(l) > 1`